# how should I use in one where clause check one field by more than one value

Tags: php, laravel, where-clause

```
          where("mime_type", "not like", "image%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "video%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "audio%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "application%")
```

how should use all of them in one where() in laravel eloquent model

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prepare the data to be excluded before running the `->where()` method:

```
$toExclude = ['image', 'video', 'audio', 'application'];
        
$excludedValues = array_map(
    callback: fn($value) => ['mime_type', 'not like', $value . '%'],
    array: $toExclude
);

$images = Image::query()->where($excludedValues)->get();
```

or, without using `array_map`:

```
$toExclude = ['image', 'video', 'audio', 'application'];
        
$excludedValues = [];
        
foreach ($toExclude as $value) {
    $excludedValues[] = ['mime_type', 'not like', $value . '%'];
}
        
$images = Image::query()->where($excludedValues)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereNotIn method.

Like:

`$admins = \App\Models\Users::whereNotIn('role', ['customer','employee','vendor'])->get();`

So You get results of users who are not `customer`,`vendor`, `employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's `orWhere` method.

```
 ->where("mime_type", "not like", "image%")
 ->orWhere("mime_type", "not like", "video%")
```

For more detail please refer document https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-not-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Pass array in where clause.

```
$exclude_values = [
        ['mime_type' ,'not like','image'.'%'],
        ['mime_type' ,'not like','video'.'%'],
        ['mime_type' ,'not like','audio'.'%'],
        ['mime_type' ,'not like','application'.'%'],
    ];
    $wherein_query = \App\Models\ModelName::where($exclude_values)
                ->get();
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple way to resolve this:
Make the where function inside `->where()` like this:

```php
$your_model->where(function ($query) {
  $query->where("mime_type", "not like", "image%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "video%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "audio%")
        ->where("mime_type", "not like", "application%");
})
```

It will generate like:

```sql
where
  (
    `mime_type` not like 'image%'
    and `mime_type` not like 'video%'
    and `mime_type` not like 'audio%'
    and `mime_type` not like 'application%'
  )
```

Hope this help.